# Difference between Action<T> as parameter and plain lambda as parameter

Tags: c#, lambda

I was experimenting with multithreading when I fund something which I can't explain. The following code compiles and works without errors:

```
new Thread(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello")).Start();
```

Whereas this one doesn't:

```
Action a = () => Console.WriteLine("World");
new Thread(a).Start();
```

Why, what's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Lambda can be converted into any number of possible `delegate`s or expression trees. An `Action` is a *specific* delegate type. There's no [Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread(v=vs.110).aspx) for `Thread` that accepts, specifically, an `Action`.

Here, specifically, the `Lambda` is turned into a `ThreadStart` delegate.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the `Thread` constructor doesn't take an `Action`, it takes a `ThreadStart` delegate.

The compiler will infer the right type for you when you use a lambda expression which means that the two pieces of code looks like this:

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => Console.WriteLine("Hello"))).Start();
```

and

```
Action a = new Action(() => Console.WriteLine("World"));
new Thread(a).Start();
```

So in the second case you've said "This is an `Action`" and then the compiler won't find an overload of the constructor that takes an `Action`, and then produce a compiler error.

You could say that the compiler could auto-inject code that just converted this, since they are both delegates without parameters with a void return type, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The lambda in your first expression yields a `ThreadStart` delegate, where the second expression is an `Action`, and there is no conversion between `ThreadStart` and `Action`.

This would be the working equivalent for your second expression:

```
ThreadStart a = () => Console.WriteLine("World");
new Thread(a).Start();
```